# kubuntu stuck on opening screen showing cursor

Tags: boot, login

My Kubuntu 18.04 system was working, but then I attempted unsuccessfully to change my username using **usermod**.  I created a new user named **temp**, gave **temp** root privileges. logged out, logged in again as **temp** and did **usermod -l paul paula**.  I then attempted to rename **/home/paul** to **/home/paula**.

I unfortunately don't remember everything that happened after that, except that the **users** command showed three copies of **paul**.  In scrambling around to fix that problem, I somehow managed to get my Kubuntu into its current sad state.

Now my Kubuntu gets stuck on bootup.  I see the Kubuntu logo and then a screen with just a cursor.  And there it sits.

I think I've narrowed down the problem to one of the scripts in **/etc/rc.d** - but which one?  It's whatever script calls for the initial login.

Comment: What happens when you revert the changes that seem to have caused your current problem? Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1268826/edit) your question with the exact details of what you changed?

Comment: I wish I knew everything that happened, but I was misled by the fact that the procedure for changing the username seemed so straightforward.  Now I think I'll need somehow to work with the system in its current state; how it got there doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Adding those details definitely helps narrow down the issue. Have you tried to create another new user for yourself?  You should probably do this from a root shell prompt (booting into recovery mode with networking). Don't forget to give the new user sudo privileges. When you reboot, make sure you choose the new user and verify that you can call sudo - then you can archive or delete the "broken" users

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to one of the script in /etc/rc.d that calls for the initial login -- but which one?